# R how to remove first row of duplicate values from a big column

Tags: r, duplicates, row

in R I have a file (df) consisting in 2 very big columns, A and B (aprox. 1000000 elements each). I know I have many duplicate values in A. I know how to remove the duplicates (remove second rows of each duplicate):

```
df1 = df[!duplicated(df$A), ]
```

but I would like to remove the first rows in the duplicate and keep the second rows. For instance, in the following example, I would like to remove 71 T and keep 71 C, NOT the other way around:

```
A   B

4   A
8   C
21  T
71  T
71  C
74  C
75  G
78  C
86  T
```

Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Are you looking for `df[!duplicated(df$A, fromLast=T), ]`?

Comment: Excellent ! @PierreLafortune. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr, you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(A) %>% slice(-1)
```

If you need to arrange column A in a specific way first, you can incorporate arrange into the mix as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(A) %>% group_by(A) %>% slice(-1) # sorts A in ascending order
```

Comment: Thank you @user3949008 for your help !

Comment: Sorry, it should have been A. Edited.